# How to make a <div> element to follow another but not in the line?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm making a snake game. I'm trying to make the player turn so the body elements of it should follow the head and should be created after it's head.

```
<!--Player-->
<div class="snake"></div>
```

Ok. This is the snake and the game is throwing all of the parts inside. Head and body parts.

```
      var pos = 100;
//Snake Grows

    var grow = function() {
        $('<div></div>').addClass('body').prependTo('.snake').css('left', pos * score * 1.1 +'%');
    }
```

This function is called later when snake eats the food. It creates a block that prepends to the snake's body but when it turns it just goes vertically. Is there a follow() function or something simmilar that will make the body parts go through same path as the head? If not any ideas how to solve this? I'm new to programing so any advices would be helpful.

Comment: That's really not the way to create a game, you should instead use a canvas for that, e.g: http://cssdeck.com/labs/classic-snake-game-with-html5-canvas

Comment: I don't konw how to use it. I'll try  to learn the basics. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a [Simple Snake Game](http://jsfiddle.net/8uVEh/) I made a while back for fun using the HTML 5 Canvas. I think this would be good to look at for an idea on how about to go making a Snake Game.

The way how a snake game works is very much like an array or blocks that you constantly add on and remove from. The blocks themselves do not move at all and you just need to know where to place the next block, and when you place a new block remove the last one. For example where `this.snake` is an array:

```
// dirX and dirY would be where the next block should go
this.move = function(dirX,dirY) {
    if(!this.checkPower()) this.snake.splice(0, 1); // remove first only if did not get powerup.
    var newX = this.snake[this.snake.length-1].x+dirX;
    var newY = this.snake[this.snake.length-1].y+dirY;
    this.snake.push(new Node(newX, newY)); // Add new node to last, pos based on direction.
}
```

Notice that the blocks are not moving, we just add a new block based on where we are going. This way if the user eats some food all we need to do is not remove the block at the end of the snake for the `move()` function. Here is a visual diagram Where `U` would mean if we where holding the `Up key`:

[image]

Notice there is no movement needed, which makes things mush easier, as you just need to know where to place the next block and remove the last block. So it looks like it's moving but it's really not.

While this uses the HTML 5 Canvas the same idea can be applied in CSS or HTML for visuals.

Answer (score 0):

Check where the last snake block's position was have the block before it go there. That's what all the blocks should be doing- going into the position the last block was.